# What do I call the model that I have "transferred" from in transfer learning?

Tags: neural-networks, terminology, transfer-learning

I am trying to document some machine learning artefacts, we have two models a and b. a and b are trained using the same data, they are trained with the same embedding and with the same algorithm and the same regime. What is different is that I used different pre trained models to initialise them (I did transfer learning from different models twice). One works better than the other (a) and I want to document both what the model I used was and what I have rejected.

What do I call the model that I used to build a? The "transferred model?" the "donor model"? the "source model"? What do I call the rejected model?

Comment: Yup that's what I meant - edited now :)